# Auto Load controller function to show data in a view - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can i Auto Load controller function to show data in a view?

Controller function, receive data from a model (query to the database).

And i want to show the info in the view, automatically.

Comment: How do you load the `view`? Just pass the `data` to it `$this->load->view('viewfile', $yourData);`

Comment: @HashemQolami I have done that, but doesnt show anything.

Comment: @HashemQolami Your right. I was doing the wrong thing. Thanks! :)